# Output of weighted percentile distributions with multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr, hmisc

I am relatively new to R after years of SAS coding.  I am trying to output many different weighted percentiles on multiple groups.  I am trying the following code -- please note that "VarName" in the function call is a bogus name to provide some confidentiality:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)
quantile_df <- function(x) {
  tibble(
    val = Hmisc::wtd.quantile(x,  weights=WT_Fact, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.0), na.rm = TRUE)
  )
}
 
 
df1 <- FeesBalances %>% group_by(Sales_Volume) %>% 
 reframe(quantile_df(VarName))
```

This code produces a tibble with 135 rows, 15 each for each of the 9 values of Sales Volume.  The values all appear reasonable, although I have not cross-checked to SAS output.  However, I am getting 9 warnings from reframe.

The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `quantile_df(VarName)`.
ℹ In group 1: `Sales_Volume = 1`.
Caused by warning in `x + weights`:
! longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

Please help an old dog learn some new tricks as I try to learn this language.

My code produced a tibble with apparently accurate data.

Comment: Welcome to SO, David! It would be easier to help you if 
you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) 
including a snippet of your data or some fake data, e.g. you could use one of the built-in datasets like `iris`, 
replace `Sales_Volume` by `Species`, `VarName` by e.g. `Sepal.Length` and so on. Moreover, it looks like `WT_Fact` is a vector in 
your global environment instead of a column of your data. That may explain the warnings and may result in wrong results.

Comment: Thank you Stefan for your note.  I accept the gentle chastisement regarding reproducible example, and will do better in the future.  FYI WT_Fact is actually a column in data.

Comment: FWIW when I attempted to create a reproducible example using the Fisher Iris data I was not successful in doing so.  I must therefore conclude that it is something else, probably in the data, that is causing these warnings.  Thank you, but I suspect under the circumstances this question should be closed.